# Query Shortcode from a multisite to appear on a different site?

Tags: plugins, php, multisite, shortcode

So, I have a map shortcode on a page template that is used like this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[bgmp-map]');
```

The shortcode works great, but I was hoping to query the site that the shortcode displays, and display that on ANOTHER site within my multi site... is that possible?  I want to do this because it would be so much easier to bring that information in and manage it only in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this... here's what you need to do if anyone needs to do something similar:

SO, you can't really query a site, but you can query pages on sites... so what I did was make a new page on the site where everything looked good, embed the shortcode, query that page and the content only on the other site.  You NEED to have the site switch to that one to retrieve it though on the other multisite. You can look that up in the wp admin under "sites" to see the site ids.

Example:

```
 <?php switch_to_blog(2); ?>
//changes to the site you want to query
 <? $the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id=229' );
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
 $the_query->the_post();
 the_content();
endwhile;
 wp_reset_postdata();
 ?>
```